# Integration between Axios and RequireJS fail

Tags: axios, requirejs

I have a error in integration between RequireJS and Axios:

```html
<HEAD>
<script src="3party/require.js"></script> 

<SCRIPT>
//work!
 requirejs(['/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery'],()=>{
        console.debug($);
     })

//error  
 requirejs(['/bower_components/axios/dist/axios'],()=>{
        axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function(response){ 
              console.log(response.status); // ex.: 200
            });  
     });
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD
```

The URL is a test service, the error below occurs.

```
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "/bower_components/axios/dist/axios"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5)
```

Any URL, or even the below line, the error occurs:

```
console.debug(axios);
```

I am using the below version:

```
"axios": "^0.19.2",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the AXIOS code and it does support AMD. So you need to use it as a regular AMD:

```
<HEAD>
<script src="3party/require.js"></script> 

<SCRIPT>
 requirejs(['/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery'],()=>{
        console.debug($);
     })

 requirejs(['/bower_components/axios/dist/axios'],(axios)=>{ // axios is given as a argument to a your callback
        axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get').then(function(response){ 
              console.log(response.status); // ex.: 200
            });  
     });
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

AXIOS will not be available as global but as a local module when you require it :)